# How to return regular expression match without letters

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code

```
Function simpleCellRegex(Myrange As Range) As String
    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    'Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim strReplace As String
    Dim strOutput As String

    strPattern = "_[a-zA-Z][0-9]"

       If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = Myrange.Value
        strReplace = "_"

        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        If regEx.test(strInput) Then
            simpleCellRegex = regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace)
        Else
            simpleCellRegex = "Not matched"
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Right now, the strReplace variable is hard-coded. Is there a way to replace the matched substring with the same substring without letters?
Ie.,

If the Input is

"bs_oper36_a01"

I would like to output
"bs_oper36_01". However the last several characters could change, so would it be possible to make the output dynamic, ie., if the input changes?

Comment: May help if you show some data and expected output.

Comment: Try `strPattern = "(_)[a-zA-Z]([0-9])"` and `strReplace = "$1$2"`, which should replace the matched text with capture group #1 and capture group #2.

Comment: Thanks Domenic, success!